# Sharepoint Collaboration using List

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, collaboration

We are developing a SharePoint 2013 app for a Club.

We have two SP groups (Coaches, Players) .

As a Coach, I want to setup Notes about a particular player in my team, These notes would be Comments or notes or simple text about the behavior of player and must be hidden from the Player.

For setting up the notes we need to select the Player (profile) and then these notes(comments) should be shared among the other Coaches and will not be visible to Player him/her self.

Player and Coach are SharePoint Groups instead of AD groups.

For Building App:
What is best way to do this?
If we use the list what based template I should use for Notes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list from custom template.  The list may have two lookup fields one for player and another for coach and a multiline text field for storing comments.  Moreover,  the list will have permissions for coach group only.

Comment: Nadeem. Can you refer me some example where we can add a  look up column from People and group .. I couldn't find yet. I have created a list with Generic Grid and have added two field but How can I make Teacher column as look.. thanks

Comment: Lookups can be used in case the user names are saved in lists. However,  in your case you need to use two user fields instead of lokups as you are referencing users from people and group.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to consider `Discussions List` as a basis.
Below are provided some descriptions of required customization.

### List

Based on `Discussions List`.

Players List

[image]

**Create Player**

[image]

**Create Note (or add note about player)**

In order to add Note select Player item and then type note as demonstrated below

[image]

### Content Types

- `Player`, contains Player column (User field type). This content type derives from Folder content type. Corresponds to `Discussion` content type
- `Note`, contains Comment column (Rich Text field type) Corresponds to `Message` content type

### Permissions

Specify unique permissions for Players list

[image]

Comment: Vadim, thanks for nice elaboration.As I am new to Sharepoint 2013 and you illustrated it using out of box capabilities. We want to add all these steps using the App(Coding) and almost we want to have same UI in app you presented. Will this be same or different when We want to try it with app. Because in App we need to draw the UI . Place the buttons and action.